# angularjs: undoing $setValidity()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm overriding form validation on a specific text field by conditionally changing ng-valid to ng-invalid with either

```
$setValidity('', false);
```

or

```
$valid = false
```

Thing is, I'd like to undo the effects of the above statements as soon as the user finishes retyping another value that complies with normal form validation. So far, when I use either of the above statements the change "sticks". How can I undo it at will? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use ng-change sending the form element as a parameter. Write your functionality(validation based), then use this:

```
function
your validation check
if
// value doesn't compile with normal form validation
formelement.$setValidity("required", false);
else
//value that complies with normal form validation:
formelement.$setValidity("required", true);
```

Comment: There is a germ of a solution here. I would need to invoke this method when the user retypes a value. How do I connect that event with the execution of this method?

Comment: Disregard the above comment. I meant to write:  As you say, I would need to invoke this method with ng-change when the user retypes a value. But how do I manually invoke the angularjs form validation to determine what condition exists?

Comment: The way i said above send the form element in the ng-change function call and play with its validity the way you need it to taking the above reference